# SQL: Column "%cointelegraph.com%" does not exist

Tags: sql, vertica

I need your help.

I am trying to run a query where I search domains but I get this error:

```
Column "%cointelegraph.com%" does not exist
```

The code I am referring to is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fact f 
WHERE   f.country_id in (840) 
AND f.domain in ("%cointelegraph.com%","%coindesk.com%")
```

Do you know how to fix this error?

I will just add that I use SQL Vertica.

---------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off and you should be using two `LIKE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM fact
WHERE country_id = 840 AND
      (domain LIKE '%cointelegraph.com%' OR domain LIKE '%coindesk.com%');
```

The `LIKE` operator does not support any `IN` construct in standard SQL.

Comment: this does not help, I get same error

Comment: I doubt that you are running the code in my answer.

Comment: Well, I did :))

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

You should do it as :

```
SELECT * 
FROM fact f 
WHERE f.country_id = 840 
AND (f.domain LIKE '%cointelegraph.com%' OR f.domain LIKE '%coindesk.com%')
```

Comment: this does not help, I get same error

Comment: This should return you the correct result; Is the query in post is a complete query ?

Answer (score 0):

String literals, in SQL, are enclosed in *single* quotes, not the double quotes you are using.

Double quotes are used to denote *identifiers*, that is, column names, database wide expressions like `CURRENT_DATE`, tables or views, etc.

If you use a reserved word, like `"AS"` or `"USER"`, or have letters that do not belong into a programmer word, like the spaces in
`"This is a quoted column name"` , you *have* to enclose the identifier in double quotes. Vertica, like any RDBMS abiding to the ANSI SQL standard, is convinced you mean a column name or pseudo column name at this place in the syntax, and the error message you get is consistent with that.

So this is how your query should look:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fact f 
WHERE   f.country_id in (840) 
-- AND f.domain in ("%cointelegraph.com%","%coindesk.com%")  -- not this
-- AND f.domain in ('%cointelegraph.com%','%coindesk.com%')  -- almost this
   OR domain LIKE '%cointelegraph.com%' OR domain LIKE '%coindesk.com%' -- better this
```

The fact that you use percent signs around the domain names, means you want to use a similarity pattern, not a string to compare for equality, so the `IN()` predicate does not apply; you need to use two `LIKE` predicates `OR`-ed together.